# iOS Convert NSNumber to NSString

Tags: ios, crash, nsnumberformatter

Sometimes when I try to cover NSNumber to NSString I am getting crash. But unfortunately I am unable to debug Xcode's crash log, and I am not sure exactly what value is causing the crash.
Here is crash log of Xcode. Please let me know what additional check I should do to fix the crash.

> -[NSNumberFormatter _regenerateFormatter]
>
> -[NSNumberFormatter stringForObjectValue:]

```
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
        NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:value];  // crash
        string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];
        return string;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
```

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libicucore.A.dylib              0x00000001801acdf0 ulocimp_getKeywordValue + 204 (uloc.cpp:776)
1   libicucore.A.dylib              0x00000001801accc8 uloc_getKeywordValue + 112 (uloc.cpp:734)
2   libicucore.A.dylib              0x00000001801a1de0 ucurr_forLocale + 192 (ucurr.cpp:526)
3   libicucore.A.dylib              0x000000018022be84 icu::DecimalFormatSymbols::initialize(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&, signed char, icu::NumberingSystem const*) + 1264 (dcfmtsym.cpp:489)
4   libicucore.A.dylib              0x000000018022c1fc icu::DecimalFormatSymbols::DecimalFormatSymbols(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 324 (dcfmtsym.cpp:110)
5   libicucore.A.dylib              0x000000018033a978 unum_open + 396 (unum.cpp:75)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018043f088 __cficu_unum_open + 64 (CFICULogging.c:2292)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018045d60c CFNumberFormatterCreate + 276 (CFNumberFormatter.c:129)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181c5477c -[NSNumberFormatter _regenerateFormatter] + 236 (NSNumberFormatter.m:270)
9   Foundation                      0x0000000181c35a74 -[NSNumberFormatter stringForObjectValue:] + 344 (NSNumberFormatter.m:708)
10  ProjectName                     0x0000000102267918 -[My method] + 184
```

Comment: That is not a crash log. Please show the crash log.

Comment: I have updated @matt

Comment: That's actually quite interesting. Maybe you are hitting the iOS bug where sometimes the NSLocale is unavailable. Try specifying the formatter's locale explicitly. A bare number formatter without any configuration is rarely useful anyway; see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html for some examples of how you should be talking.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this crash? @Kam12

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to iOS 12.x and it is still active.
You can fix the problem by using following:
`[@(value.integerValue) stringValue]`